# Add JavaScript files in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new in `asp.net mvc` and I am trying to include `.js` files in my project but I could not access it on my browser. Like it.

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/responds.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery-1.11.3.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jssor.slider-22.0.15.mini.js")
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

Anyone can help me, how can I add these files in `mvc` project? These files exists in `Scripts` folder.

Comment: Do you want to add them to a particular view or the entire application?

Comment: Yes, it is my requirement.

Comment: In your project you will have a folder named `App_Start` which will have a file named `BundleConfig.cs`. Check in there whether you've got the appropriate bundles set. for example `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/responds.js")` would be `bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include("~/Scripts/respond.js"));` in `BundleConfig.cs` file

Comment: Yes, It is exists there.

Comment: How do you know the scripts aren't included? Do you get 404's?

Comment: Yes, when I open it in view page. It gives me 404 error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have solved my problem by just drag and drop script files from `Scripts` folder to at desired place in `Index.cshtml` and `Visual studio` auto generate below code.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jssor.slider-22.1.5.mini.js"></script>
```

Which includes the script files in `asp.net MVC`.

Answer (score 13):

You can manually add a `.js` file to a view with the following example code

```
@model YourNameSpace.ViewModels.YourViewModel
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/yourScript.js")
```

If you want the files to be bundled & you can add them in `App_Start/BundleConfig.cs`

Example:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle(("~/bundles/customBundle").Include(
     "~/Scripts/yourScript.js", 
     "~/Scripts/anotherScript.js");
}
```

---

You can render your script files for the whole application in the `~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml` file or any `master page` by adding the following code

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/customBundle")
```

---

You can inspect the `.js` file by browsing to the root of your application & add the path of the `.js` file or `bundle` (for this example)

```
http://localhost:9654/bundles/customBundle
http://localhost:9654/Scripts/yourScript.js
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use C# code to calculate & generate the right file address as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='@Url.Content("~/Content/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js")'></script>
```

This pattern can use in *.cshtml files.